# Should I convert immutable Map object to plain JS object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, immutable.js

We are using `immutable.js` module in our `react-native` project. Snippet of our  reducer is given below.

```
const initialState = Map({
      key: "",
    });

    export default function xyzReducer(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_XYZ:
          return state.set("key", action.payload);
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

**My question is: Do I need to convert the `Map` type to plain JavaScript object before updating my state?**

The reason I ask this question is because I've a component `connected` to store, My store gets updated but for some reason this update does not get reflected in the component. So, I thought that there must be something wrong with the way we've used `immutable.js`, Hence I need validation from this community.

Comment: Redux's internal state should be immutable and libraries such as immutable.js help the developer to build, maintain and update an immutable state. So, you do not need to convert `initialState` immutable.js `Map` to a plain JavaScript object.

Said so, it could help to see the code of the container's component and the component itself to understand why it is not updated when the state change.

Comment: As a side note: when you update the state for action `ACTION_XYZ` you do `state.set("key", action.payload)` but what is that `action.payload`? Is a JavaScript value type, such as number, string, boolean or a JavaScript object? In the latter case, you are setting a non-immutable object inside an immutable state. You have to convert the `action.payload` in an immutable object before setting it into the map.

Comment: @Andrea Can you please explain the statement "You have to convert the action.payload in an immutable object before setting it into the map."?

Comment: Sure. The idea is that your Redux's state is an immutable object. This means that if your state is a map with <key, value> pairs, all the value must be value type (simple types, like number, string, ecc...) or immutable objects too. So, when you set `action.payload` as value of key `"key"` you have to convert the payload in an immutable object. Otherwise, next time you try to get the value with `state.get("key")` you will get a plain object not an immutable one.